# Auto crop an image white border from all four side in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, java-io, javax.imageio

[image: Sample Image]

I want to crop all four side white spaces.
the easiest way to auto crop the white border out of an image in java? Thanks in advance...

```
public class TrimWhite {

    public class TrimWhite {
        private BufferedImage img;

        public TrimWhite(File input) {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException( "Problem reading image", e );
            }
        }

        public void trim() {
            int width  = getTrimmedWidth();
            int height = getTrimmedHeight();

            BufferedImage newImg = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics g = newImg.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage( img, 0, 0, null );
            img = newImg;
        }

        public void write(File f) {
            try {
                ImageIO.write(img, "bmp", f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException( "Problem writing image", e );
            }
        }

        private int getTrimmedWidth() {
            int height       = this.img.getHeight();
            int width        = this.img.getWidth();
            int trimmedWidth = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                for(int j = width - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if(img.getRGB(j, i) != Color.WHITE.getRGB() &&
                            j > trimmedWidth) {
                        trimmedWidth = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return trimmedWidth;
        }

        private int getTrimmedHeight() {
            int width         = this.img.getWidth();
            int height        = this.img.getHeight();
            int trimmedHeight = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                for(int j = height - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if(img.getRGB(i, j) != Color.WHITE.getRGB() &&
                            j > trimmedHeight) {
                        trimmedHeight = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return trimmedHeight;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        TrimWhite trim = new TrimWhite(new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\New folder (2)\\Untitled.png"));
        trim.trim();
        trim.write(new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\New folder (2)\\test.png"));
    }
}
}
```

[image: Output]

I want output must crop all four side white spaces  please help!

Comment: you want an answer and then you want "the easiest"!! does your method work to begin with?

Comment: Have a look how it's done in ImageJ (which is written in Java): https://github.com/fiji/Fiji_Plugins/blob/master/src/main/java/fiji/selection/Select_Bounding_Box.java

Comment: Yes it is partially working #gpasch